# Convert B64 buffer to HEX

Tags: c, openssl, hex, base64

I have a buffer defined as:

```
        char *p;
```

That is being filled by a function

```
        p = base64( (unsigned char *)digest, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH );
```

And is printable in cleartext using:

```
    printf( "RESULT IN B64: %x\n", p);
```

I am using the OPENSSL libraries (hmac.h, etc..)

Any thoughts or hints as to how to convert this string from B64 to HEX? (not simple ASCII to hex of course)

Comment: You are aware that `p` is not a buffer, right? It's just a pointer, and requires extra memory allocation to act as a buffer.

Comment: Google "B64 buffer to HEX"